# Get return code of ssh command in bash

Tags: bash, macos, ssh

I need to get the return/error code of an ssh command in my bash script. The command uses applescript to move a file on the remote machine to the trash. This is part of a larger script:

```
ssh $login "bash -s" <<-EOF
    error=(osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to move POSIX file \"$remote_filepath\" to trash");
    [[ -n "$error" ]] && { echo -e "\nCannot move file to trash on remote mac"; exit 1; };
EOF
# echo $?; exit
[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && exit 1
# more code ...
```

My aim is to have the ssh command exit with code 1 if the osascript fails, so I can catch the error and abort the rest of the script.

The ssh runs successfully, the file is indeed moved to the trash. Apparently osascript runs fine, because the error message is not shown. Still, the ssh return code is 1 (I checked it with the `echo $?` statement. This is where I'm stuck. I'd appreciate any insight on what's wrong here.

Comment: I assume when typing this up that you missed the `$` in `error=$(osascript ...` because without it the script of course won't be run.

Comment: Hm. No, the $ isn't there. Why should it be? It's a local variable. The file is trashed without the $.

Comment: Double bracket is the cause of your trouble: `[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit`

Comment: @F.Hauri Both double and single brackets do the same thing here.

Comment: The command `error=(osascript -e "foo")` doesn't execute anything. It creates an array of three elements. To execute a command and capture the output, which is what I assume you want to do, you need to say `error=$(osascript -e "foo")`.

Comment: @ccarton That seems strange, why is my file trashed then?

Comment: `ssh $login "mv \"$remote_file\" ~/.Trash"` is a little simpler and would appear to be equivalent.

Comment: @chepner True, it's simpler, but also rather dumb. It  just overwrites previous copies in the trash, unlike the Finder. For all that I could have done a `rm`. I'd like the copies in the trash, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @ccarton You're right about the missing `$`. I'd done so much editing on the script that I missed it. I'll add my own answer with another workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `[[ -n "$error" ]]` command sets the error code to 1. You need to use the negation of that test. Try:

`[[ -z "$error" ]] || { echo -e ...`

Comment: @Timm Glad I could help. A best practice is to always use this negative test when checking errors because it preserves the success code. For example, if it was me, I would change the last line in the same way, or even just add `|| exit` at the end of the ssh command. That will do the same thing. With no argument `exit` will use `$?`.

Answer (score 0):

After all the problems with `osascript` not returning a real error code I decided to just check if the file was moved at all, like this:

```
# move file to trash on remote mac
ssh $login "bash -s" <<-EOF
  osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to move POSIX file \"$remote_filepath\" to trash" > /dev/null;
EOF
[[ ! -e "$remote_filepath" ]] || { printf "\nCannot move file to trash on remote mac" && exit 1; }
```

Just seems simpler and easier to maintain for me. Thanks everyone for the input!